# Many Java collections implement the add method - they actually deep copy

Tags: java, collections, methods, naming-conventions

I am just grasping collections and found that the add() methods actually deep copy objects into the collections.  Should they be called something like "copyInto" ?

```
import java.util.*;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set <Frog> setOfFrogs = new HashSet <Frog>();

        Frog frog1 = new Frog("Kermit");
        Frog frog2 = new Frog("Bob");

        setOfFrogs.add(frog1);
        setOfFrogs.add(frog2);

        frog1.name = "May";
        frog2.name = "Mary";

        for (Frog eachFrog : setOfFrogs){
            System.out.println(eachFrog.name);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints: "May" and "Mary".

Sorry all it is a shallow copy.  I need to get this "by reference" business into my thick head...

Comment: The `add` methods do **not** make deep copies.  What leads you to believe this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.add(..)` simply adds the reference to the object in the collection. It does no deep copying. For example, if you change the object, the change will be reflected in the collection.

Comment: I am using the HashSet class implementing the Set interface.  I end up with two completely separate instances...

Comment: It would be clearer (IMO) to say that it adds the *references* to the collection. Then you have two references to the same object (one in the calling code, one in the collection). That makes it clear that it's not copying anything but the reference.

Comment: So a copy of the references was added.  Where is the deep copy?

Comment: Oooops...   True, so how do you make sure the Set will not contain duplicates?

Comment: You just use the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods like normal, of course.  Perhaps you aren't overriding those methods?

Comment: If you are overriding `hashCode()`, don't use the frog's name in the hashCode! Or if you do, don't change it once it's in the Set. If you change the Frog's name after it's already in the HashSet, the HashSet will *not* know about the change, and your Frog may well be in the wrong bucket. That means that attempts to add or query Frogs with either of the names will not behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Collection works on object references -> thats the reason why you cannot add primitives into colection and must wrap them into object representation.